# Can I use angular.js with an object, not a function?

Tags: angularjs

Here's my situation: I've got a Javascript object in an application that I've already created that looks a little something like this...

```
var foo = foo || {};
foo.name = "";
foo.gender = "";

foo.loadUser = function() {
    // Some other stuff here
    foo.name = "Joe";
    foo.gender = "Fella";

    $("#welcome).text("Hello " + foo.name + " you sure are a swell " + foo.gender + "!");    
}
```

Now, I've decided I don't like my mixing of logic and presentation, so I want to remove that line of jquery, and just have angular.js update the text for me with some simple data-binding. So I've loaded angular.js and added this little line..

```
<div ng-app>
<div id="welcome" ng-controller="foo">Hello {{foo.name}}! 
     You sure are a swell {{foo.gender}}!</div>
```

The problem is that, when doing this, I get an error along the lines of...

> Error: Argument 'foo' is not a function, got Object

Looking at the angular.js Getting Started example, it looks like I might need to go back and rewrite my entire foo object (along with all my other code) in a format like...

```
function foo($scope) {
  $scope.name = '';
  $scope.gender = '';

  $scope.loadUser = function() {
    //Other stuff here
    $scope.name = "Joe";
    $scope.gender = "Fella"            
  }

}
```

...which might work (I haven't tried it yet), but I'm not sure I want to rewrite all of my code to fit this new format. I have a lot more objects than just foo, and in real life foo has a lot more stuff in it. (Heck, I don't even call it "foo"!)

Is there any way I can get data binding to work without rewriting all of my objects as function?

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for but you should still be able to use your foo objects as they are in an Angular controller like this:

```
function Controller($scope){
    $scope.foo = foo;
    foo.loadUser();
}
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aRXM5/) for an example. You may also want to move your objects into a [service](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.creating_services) or factory as described in Lesson 2 of [this article](http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-sticky-notes-pt-1-architecture/).

Answer (score 0):

This might seem obvious but have you tried `ng-controller="foo.loadUser"`

markup

```
<div id="welcome" ng-controller="foo.loadUser">Hello {{foo.name}}! 
     You sure are a swell {{foo.gender}}!</div>
```

angular

```
foo.loadUser = function($scope) {
    // Some other stuff here
    foo.name = "Joe";
    foo.gender = "Fella";

    $scope.foo = foo;
}
```

As long the function receives as $scope and does all the angularjs magic on that value you shouldn't have to alter you existing objects.